# pg_ctl: directory “/var/lib/postgresql/10/main” is not a database cluster directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, replication, psql, database-replication

I'm following this guide to do a replica server using postgres, I already made everything in a shell to automate it and seems fine, until i get to this command

```
pg_basebackup -h 192.168.1.103 -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -P -U replication
```

which I rewrote as

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "pg_basebackup -h "$MASTER" -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ -P -U replication"
```

Where "$MASTER" inserts my primary server IP

However right when my shell gets to run that command linux suddenly just keeps working... for around 3 minutes until it gives up, the shell resumes the script and ends the job, needless to say the command that gets stuck didn't get me the folder I was asking on from the primary server to the secondary server, the postgres log file shows me this:

```
pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main" is not a database cluster directory
```

Running

```
pg_lsclusters
```

gets me

```
 Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
 10  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

So I'm clueless of what to do next since I can't find information about this error online

Comment: Did you initialize the directory (eg. `initdb`)?

Comment: @l'L'l I dont think i did just folllowed the guide and there is no mention of initdb anywhere

Comment: It's required to initialize a database cluster. `initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main` <- if that is your intended data directory. (more info: https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/10/creating-cluster)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar problem with related to Windows-10 and PostgreSQL. I have used the below commands so that might be helpful to someone else.

```
pg_ctl.exe initdb -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data"
```

and then

```
pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" start
```

Kindly look at the below screenshot to know the outcome of the above commands.

[image: Console Output of initdb and start commands of postgresql]